# Pass an array in Typheus as url param

Tags: ruby, typhoeus

I'm using Typhoeus an want to send an array inside url params.

pass this:

```
/event?groups[]=open-forum&groups[]=armory-films
```

instead of this:

```
/event?groups[0]=open-forum&groups[1]=armory-films
```

looking the issues it seem to it is possible thanks to a [param inside ethon](https://github.com/typhoeus/ethon/commit/548033a8557a48203b7d49f3f98812bd79bc05e4):

```
 params_encoding and takes :rack
```

But how to add that parameter to a typheus request when I add that

```
Typhoeus::Request.new(endpoint,
                      method: :put,
                      headers: HEADERS,
                      params_encoding: :rack,
                      params: {
                        status: 'close',
                        shutdown_on: I18n.l(closed_at, format: :es),
                        affected_external_id: reference,
                        fqdns:fqdns
                      })
```

I get:

```
The option: params_encoding is invalid.
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was using an obsolete thyphoeus gem, this works on actual [release](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus/releases), and bigger that 1.0.0